# Not able to register selenium webdriver node on VM to the hub on Host

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a host with IP `192.168.3.146`. This IP is a static IP given from DHCP server.
Now I have VM with network configured as Bridged.

I am seeing the IP as `10.0.2.15`. 
Since it's bridged should I be getting anything in the range `192.168.3.x` assigned to the VM as well?

When I register from this VM to the host I am not able to register the web driver, it just says "Registering" and does nothing until I kill it.

Command used to register the node:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.26.0.jar -role web driver -hub http:/192.168.3.146:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -host 10.0.2.15 -browser "browserName=firefox, version=6, platform=WINDOWS"`

Also tried:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.26.0.jar -role node -port 5558 -hub http:/192.168.3.146:4444/grid/register`

NOTE: in both commands `http:/` is deliberate - please ignore it. I'm actually using `//` since I was getting error while posting I have used :/

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get this setup is to use NAT Networking, and local port forwarding. What's nice about this setup is that you can run everything offline, and not rely on a constantly changing dynamic IP address. Here's how you do that:

Configure the Guest VM to use NAT Networking, add Port Forwarding rules for ports 4444 and 5555.

**Host Machine, as Hub**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

**Guest Machine, as Node**

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -host 127.0.0.1 -port 5555 -hub http://10.0.2.2:4444/grid/register
```

I use this setup to run multiple instances of the modern.ie VM machines in VirtualBox, and it works very nicely.

Comment: Glad I stumbled onto this one, done this and now I can successfully register my Guest nodes to Host hub. Only issue now is understanding how to get a test actually running on the Guest, from a CLI test initiation on the Host.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue while trying to run the Remotely via VM's from host. I used Oracle VM Virtual Box.

Since the VM is assigned 2 different IP's one via NAT & other via Bridge adapter ...Hence Selenium node fails to register itself with the Selenium HUB as by default it registers for NAT.

***Disconnect/disable the internet of VM NAT N/W adapter for which "10.0.2.15" IP is assigned. Don't Touch the bridge adapter settings...Then try to register the node...it works.***

I would suggest to connect Bridge Adapter via VM >> Settings>> Network Screen
Please check the Links below...

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/virtualbox-guest-additions/
https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1

Hope this helps...All the best :-)

Comment: Hello Anuragh,I tried this but now use. I am using Vitualbox and I am using vagrant script to bring up the VM configured as Bridged. I am not sure how it interacts with 192.168.3.146 when VM as 10.0.2.15 which is on a difft network. I am not able to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: It's all logical mapping of network adapter which plays game over the VM with different settings. I would suggest do settings via  GUI which will be more easier for you, for the same I have added few references to my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

hmmmmm....
how about simply running selenium server on remote machine with:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.26.0.jar
```

and in your e.g. BaseTest.java (where you have your webDriver initialization) you simply add:

```
static WebDriver driver;

    private String loginBaseUrl;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {

          DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), capability);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
    }
    @Before
    public void homePageRefresh() throws IOException {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get(propertyKeysLoader("login.base.url"));
    }


    @AfterClass
    public static void closeFirefox(){
        driver.quit();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have NAT and "Host-only adapter" networks configurated for the virtual machine with default properties. I solved it using the the IP of the "Host-only adapter".

For me, the IP of NAT is 10.0.2.15 (same as you) and the IP of "Host-only adapter" is 192.168.56.101. So I used:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.26.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://`192.168.3.146`:4444/grid/register -port 5558 -host `192.168.56.101` -browser "browserName=firefox, version=6, platform=WINDOWS"

Comment: It's strange, because the node is registering himself using NAT and the hub send requests to the node using Host-only adapter, but it works for me..

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Where to check these address in Virtual box ? and which one to use in command to register as a node